# How to waterproof inside cedar shed?

Tags: framing, waterproofing, shed, lumber

I want to build this shed like the picture below (I got from someone else) using my leftover cedar fence pickets:

[image]

However I don't know if it will leak water from the side. There isn't much protection from water to the inside. What about the edges around the shed on the roof? How to seal everything inside?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look closely at the boards on the inside, you will see they are overlapping, the top edge being behind the bottom edge of the board above (behind when viewed from the *outside*). This is standard clapboard type construction (although many modern clapboards have a tapered upper edge and the overlap is much greater). Rain tends to drip off the lower edge of the board and proceed downward, not into the joints.

The doors are probably tongue in groove which would resist moisture penetration by creating a circuitous path. Also, moisture that gets into the joint tends to cause it to swell and further seal the joint (somewhat).

The roof joints largely depend on overhang to keep water out.

In general, falling rain not whipped by high winds would largely stay outside.

However this type of construction is not meant to be very watertight, only keep the large majority of the water out. If you have sensitive materials that must be kept very dry, you would probably need to line the shed with a real membrane seal.

If you just want a little increased protection, you could seal the joints with caulk or silicone sealant. Most sealants prefer painted surfaces, so if you are not finishing the surface, look for one that says it bonds to wood.

Comment: Yes the boards are overlapping from the inside. Two questions (if you don't mind): how much overlapping is required? About 1" or so? Also the picture showed about 6" overhang. Is that enough or is there standard?

Comment: There are no standards for sheds (although there are recommended guidelines for houses, which do not apply).  A 1" overlap will accomplish the drip goals, but the framing shown looks a bit flimsy. You need to make sure the sides have sufficient vertical support holding up the lateral boards.  I would use at least 2x3s. a 6" overhang keeps most rain away from the roof joint.